# The seed for cycle XXX has not been computed yet

Tags: baking

On the mainnet, I can get the baking rights up to 5 cycles in advance.

For example, we are currently on cycle 146, and I observe the following:

```
# returns succesfully:
./tezos-client -A mainnet-node.tzscan.io  rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/baking_rights?cycle=151

# returns an error:
/tezos-client -A mainnet-node.tzscan.io  rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/baking_rights?cycle=152
```

The error is `The seed for cycle 152 has not been computed yet  (latest known seed is for cycle 151)`. That is, the seed is computed 5 cycles in advance.

On the alphanet (current cycle: 315), same experiment shows that the seed is only computed 3 cycles in advance:

```
# Works:
./tezos-client -A alphanet-node.tzscan.io  rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/baking_rights?cycle=318

# returns an error:
./tezos-client -A alphanet-node.tzscan.io  rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/baking_rights?cycle=319
```

Why is it different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see the constants set for the two chains via the following RPCs:

[Mainnet](http://mainnet-node.tzscan.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/constants) [Alphanet](http://alphanet-node.tzscan.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/constants)

Notice the constant for `preserved_cycles`, mainnet and alphanet is currently set with 5 and 3 cycles, respectively.

> Baking in tezos.alpha is the action of signing and publishing a block.
>   In Bitcoin, the right to publish a block is associated with solving a
>   proof-of-work puzzle. In tezos.alpha, the right to publish a block in
>   cycle n is assigned to a randomly selected roll in a randomly selected
>   roll snapshot from cycle `n-PRESERVED_CYCLES-2`.

http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html#baking-rights

Keep in mind that the random seed used to determine which snapshot will be used for cycle `n` is revealed in cycle `n-PRESERVED_CYCLES`. This is why you aren't able to get baking rights more than `PRESERVED_CYCLES` ahead because rights requires the random seed.